# Comparing two hashes with unknown values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using RSpec, is there a way to compare two hashes where I don't know what some values will be? I've tried using `instance_of`, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my test, I am creating a new device object with a POST request and want to make sure I get the right JSON response back. It's creating a UUID for the device (I'm not using a relational db), but I obviously won't know what that value will be and don't really care.

```
post "/projects/1/devices.json", name: 'New Device'

expected = {'name' => 'New Device', 'uuid' => instance_of(String), 'type' => 'Device'}

JSON.parse(body).should == expected
```

And I get the following error:

```
 1) DevicesController API adds a new device to a project
     Failure/Error: JSON.parse(body).should == expected
       expected: {"name"=>"New Device", "uuid"=>#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x5a27147d @klass=String>, "type"=>"Device"}
            got: {"name"=>"New Device", "uuid"=>"ef773465-7cec-48fd-b2a7-f1da10d1595a", "type"=>"Device"} (using ==)
       Diff:
       @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
        "name" => "New Device",
        "type" => "Device",
       -"uuid" => #<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::InstanceOf:0x5a27147d @klass=String>
       +"uuid" => "ef773465-7cec-48fd-b2a7-f1da10d1595a"
     # ./spec/api/devices_spec.rb:37:in `(root)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instance_of` is for argument matching:

```
something.should_receive(:foo).with(instance_of(String))
```

Instead of using the `==` operator you could use `include`. For example:

```
JSON.parse(body).should include('uuid', 'name' => 'New Device', 'type' => 'Device')
```

which says that the key `uuid` must be present with any value and `name` and `type` should be present with the specified value. It will also allow other keys in the hash.

I don't know of a way to achieve exactly what you're asking for with the built-in matchers.